# No such file or directory: Cygwin + Gcc

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, gfortran, include-path

I need to be able to compile a piece of code at work that was originally written for Unix based systems. I am using cygwin and the GNU gcc. Every time I try to run the make command, the program seems to compile as it should but when it gets to timing.h it produces this error:

```
Compiling: timing.c timing.h... timing.c:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target 
(all code is position independent)
 #include "timing.h"
 ^
In file included from timing.c:1:0: 
timing.h:5:26: fatal error: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/resource.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
timing.h:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 #include <sys/time.h>
 ^
timing.h:5:26: fatal error: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/resource.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [timing.o] Error 1
```

From what I have read, usually the cause of this kind of error is caused by an incorrect path. The contents of timing.h are as follows:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void timing(double* wcTime, double* cpuTime);
```

The thing that baffles me is that even-though the files are in the same directory I only get the error as it tries to include the last file. I have made sure that the $C_INCLUDE_PATH points to where the files are.

```
$ echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH
/usr/include/
```

Any help would be awesome. This has stumped me for a few days now. I am running gcc version 4.9.0.

Comment: Are you using $C_INCLUDE_PATH in the command that invokes gcc? If you could include that command line it would help.

Comment: You'll have to see exactly what command the makefile is using to compile the file. I suggest running a 'make -n'. Usually that will show you. 


I suspect that it is using a -nostdinc option or some other way of eliminating the search of the default system directories. But this is merely a guess.


If you can get the exact command line, you can add '-v' as one of the options and see exactly what gcc is attempting to do.

Comment: As far as I know I am using the include path that invokes gcc. If I grep the file I cant seem to find, I get                            $ cygcheck -l cygwin | grep resource.h
/usr/include/sys/resource.h . The command I used to set the C_INCLUDE_PATH was: export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/

Comment: I have also tried the -nostdinc option. It still breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your cygwin `/usr/include/sys` directory appears to be missing the `resource.h` file.

I just checked my cygwin installation and `resource.h` and `time.h` are both present in `/usr/include`

You might be missing a cygwin package, or your cygwin installation may need to be updated.

Comment: That seems unlikely since sys/resouce.h is part of the base system. It's possible that the user doesn't have it, but that would indicate a corrupted install.

Comment: I definitely have the file it thinks is missing.